# How to disable ip_forward for Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, kernel

This is the state of my server right after booting:

```
root@vzu01-ubuntu:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

There is no other enabled `ip_forward` configuration:

```
root@vzu01-ubuntu:~# grep -r ip_forward /etc
/etc/sysctl.conf:net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf:#net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

If I do `sysctl -p` - it disables forwarding just fine, but after a reboot ip_forward is re-enabled. Even if I put `sysctl -p` in rc.local it won't help to have ip_forward disabled on boot.

Any idea?

Comment: Hey, @wick. Did you ever fix this?  The same issue happens on 15.10 - something's enabling ip_forward and I don't know what it is.

Comment: @XCondE: hey there, yes, if you do `ip addr show` you will likely find a bridge `br0` or something like that. In my case this happened because I'd selected that option during installation. Remove that bridge (just google how) and it's solved.

Comment: thank you, that was it.  I have added an answer as reference for other people.  I have also edited your question to be more generic - it's pending peer review - I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1 - Update sysctl.conf**

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`, add the line below:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

Make sure there are no other ip_forward lines in the file or under `/etc/sysctl.d`:

```
grep -r ip_forward /etc/sysctl.d
```

If you find any, delete or comment them by putting a `#` at the start of the line.

**Part 2 - Ensure there's no other configuration that automatically re-enables forwarding**

As mentioned by @wick, Ubuntu distributions can have bridge interfaces that will turn-on forwarding after you have turned it off.

In my case it was `lcxbr0`:

```
ip addr show
(...)
3: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
```

For the interface above, edit `/etc/default/lxc-net`, and change `USE_LXC_BRIDGE` to:

```
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="false"
```

If you have any other `brX` interfaces, use a search engine to find-out how to remove them.

**Part 3 - Reboot and verify**

After rebooting, the command below should print 0:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```